# Nginx reverse proxy on another web server with redirection

Tags: redirect, nginx, configuration, proxy, reverse-proxy

The compoments of the system are [image: nginx configuration]
<sub>(source: [snag.gy](http://i.snag.gy/exwFe.jpg))</sub>
:

- "nginx server" - A
- "3rd party server" - B
- "User PC" (browser) - C

The server "A" and the user PC "C" are connected in the same network "Network A", but the server "A" and 3rd party machine "B" are connected in the network "Network B".
The goal is to access 3rd party machine "B" from the user browser "C" through the Server "A". In order to perform it, the server "A" should do reverse proxy of the 3rd party content.
Nginx server is installed and configured on the server "A". The rule for reverse proxy is:

```
location ~* ^/3rdparty/(.*)___(.*)___(.*)___(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass https://$1.$2.$3.$4?$args;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Using the rule we would like to do reverse proxy for URL:
http:///3rdparty/<3RD_PARTY_IP_URL>    =>     https://<3RD_PARTY_IP_ADDRESS>
For example:

```
http:// 192.168.237.208/3rdparty/192___168___237___222 => https://192.168.237.222
```

Actually, we want everything appended to the URL to be redirected.
For example:

```
http://192.168.237.208/3rdparty/192___168___237___222/blah/blah => https://192.168.237.222/blah/blah
```

That configuration works for us for some another setup, but the problem in this case is: on 3rd party machine "B", there is another web server which does some redirections:

```
https://192.168.237.222 => https://192.168.237.222/users/sign_in
```

So, the final result when we put the desired URI in the browser is:

```
http://192.168.237.208/3rdparty/192___168___237___222
```

the webserver on "B" takes host name of the URL and appends the redirection rule (users/sign_in), which results that browser is requesting the following URL:

```
https://192.168.237.208/users/sign_in
```

which is not available on Server "A" (actually it is on "B") => we got http error code 302 (moved temporarelly).
Are there any missing configuration rules we didn't apply? Or any other http request header parameters should be updated/forwarded?

Answer (score 0):

The backend connection to `192.168.237.222` is transparent to the client which is only connected to `192.168.237.208`

When server B (backend) sends back a `/users/sign_in` redirection, it is reversely propagated to the client, which applies it against the server he is connected to, ie server A (gateway/proxy), resulting in the erroneous request of `/users/sign_in` on `192.168.237.208`.
You need to keep in mind redirections are propagated back to and processed by the client, not the gateway/proxy.

I would do something like the following:

```
location ~* ^/3rdparty/([0-9]{1-3})___([0-9]{1-3})___([0-9]{1-3})___([0-9]{1-3})(/.*)?$ {
    proxy_pass https://$1.$2.$3.$4$5$is_args$args;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Details:

1. Modifying your regex to also match against requests with `/blah/blah` appended to the backend IP address and copy-pasting them at the end of the proxy_pass directive using another variable ($5)
2. Using [`$is_args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) nginx embedded variable instead of a question mark (avoiding to have it in a request if no args are to be passed to the backend)
3. Trying to refine the regex syntax to match IP address numbers (quick and dirty, the one I provide you with still leads to incorrect matches but is at least better than wildcards)

Now, you need to redirect clients on server B (`192.168.237.222`) to `/3rdparty/192___168___237___222/users/sign_in` which is a location that can be requested against server A (`192.168.237.208`, the only server clients are connected to) and happily forwarded to the right backend.

==========

You could also rely on the nginx [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive rather than setting it to off and make your backend server making redirection answers like `https://192.168.237.221/users/sign_in`. [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) would then allow you to rewrite those proxied answers to the right URI against `192.168.237.208`.

To do so, try something like (watchout, I am still using the lazy IP address mask):

```
    proxy_redirect     ~*^https://([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3})(/.*)?$ http://192.168.237.208/3rdparty/$1___$2___$3____$4$5;
```

I wonder if variables like [`$is_args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) and [`$args`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) are working in this context:

```
    proxy_redirect     ~*^https://([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3})(/.*)?$ http://192.168.237.208/3rdparty/$1___$2___$3____$4$5$is_args$args;
```

Comment: The docs for proxy_redirect explicitely states that the 'default' argument cannot be used when proxy_pass 'is specified using variables', which is the case fror Aleksandar. I suppose this is why it has been turned off on first hand.